# Calculating Percentage of Employees Above Weekly Hours Threshold in WinForms Grid with Dynamic Filtering

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a WinForms project with a report that displays employee data in a grid. I am trying to calculate the percentage of employees whose average weekly hours exceed a threshold entered in a textbox. The calculation works fine when no filtering is applied to the grid, but the percentage is incorrect when I filter the grid based on Agency or EmployeeType.

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
// Code to get data and calculate percentage
private HMReportsController ReportController = new HMReportsController(cGlobal.ConnectionString);
private const string ReportHeader = "Average Employee Hours Report";
private int RowCount = 0;
private double HourThreshold = 0;
private double AboveAverageCount = 0;
private double AboveAveragePercentage;

private void button_GetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    try
    {
        averageEmployeeHourModelBindingSource.DataSource = ReportController.GetAverageEmployeeHours(dateEdit_DateFrom.DateTime, dateEdit_DateTo.DateTime);                
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
    }
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}

private void buttom_Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the threshold value from the numericTextBox_hours
        double threshold = (double)numericTextBox_Hours.GetNumericValue();

        // Calculate the count of people with WeeklyAverage above the threshold
        AboveAverageCount = averageEmployeeHourModelBindingSource
            .Cast<AverageEmployeeHourModel>()
            .Count(item => item.WeeklyAverage.HasValue && item.WeeklyAverage.Value > threshold);

        // Calculate the total count of items in the grid
        RowCount = averageEmployeeHourModelBindingSource.Count;

        // Calculate the percentage
        AboveAveragePercentage = (RowCount > 0) ? (AboveAverageCount / RowCount) * 100 : 0;

        // Display the percentage in label_Percentage
        label_Percentage.Text = $"Percentage above threshold: {AboveAveragePercentage:F2}%";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The model:

```
public class AverageEmployeeHourModel
{
    public int? PayrollID { get; set; }
    public double? WeeklyAverage { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string Agency { get; set; }
    public int? NumberOfWeeks { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeType { get; set; }
}
```

The issue arises when I filter the grid on Agency or EmployeeType, and the calculation becomes inaccurate.

I've attempted to handle this by capturing column filter changes, but I observed that if I filter and then unfilter an agency, it isn't re-added to the binding source.

How can I ensure that the calculation of the percentage is accurate even when dynamic filtering is applied to the grid based on Agency or EmployeeType? Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this really related to the SQL _language_? I see no SQL above. Do you expect an SQL answer?

Comment: It seems this is a devexpress gridcontrol. Then you can simply get the `Filtered RowCount ` from `gridview.rowcount` property and the `RowCount` from `gridview.datasource.count` , or use built-in summary options of gridcontrol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by having a new model and filter bool:

```
private BindingList<AverageEmployeeHourModel> filteredEmployeeHourModels = new BindingList<AverageEmployeeHourModel>();

// Flag to indicate whether filters are applied
private bool filtersApplied = false;
```

Every time the column's filter is changed write to the new model:

```
private void gridView1_ColumnFilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateFilteredData();
}

private void UpdateFilteredData()
{
    // Clear the existing filtered data
    filteredEmployeeHourModels.Clear();

    // Iterate through the filtered rows and add them to the new model
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        if (gridView1.IsDataRow(i) && !gridView1.IsGroupRow(i) && !gridView1.IsFilterRow(i))
        {
            AverageEmployeeHourModel rowData = gridView1.GetRow(i) as AverageEmployeeHourModel;
            if (rowData != null)
            {
                filteredEmployeeHourModels.Add(rowData);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update the filtersApplied flag so that the calculation uses the filtered data
    filtersApplied = filteredEmployeeHourModels.Count > 0;
}
```

Then if there's a filter applied use the new model and if not use the original binding source:

```
private void buttom_Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (filtersApplied)
        {
            // Get the threshold value from numericTextBox_Hours
            double threshold = Convert.ToDouble(numericTextBox_Hours.Text);

            // Count the number of employees whose average weekly hours are over the threshold
            int aboveThresholdCount = filteredEmployeeHourModels.Count(emp => emp.WeeklyAverage > threshold);

            // Calculate the percentage
            double percentage = (double)aboveThresholdCount / filteredEmployeeHourModels.Count * 100;

            // Display the percentage in label_Percentage
            label_Percentage.Text = $"{percentage:F2}%";
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the threshold value from numericTextBox_Hours
            double threshold = Convert.ToDouble(numericTextBox_Hours.Text);

            // Count the number of employees whose average weekly hours are over the threshold
            int aboveThresholdCount = ((IEnumerable<AverageEmployeeHourModel>)averageEmployeeHourModelBindingSource.DataSource).Count(emp => emp.WeeklyAverage > threshold);

            // Calculate the percentage
            double percentage = ((IEnumerable<AverageEmployeeHourModel>)averageEmployeeHourModelBindingSource.DataSource).Count() > 0 ? (double)aboveThresholdCount / ((IEnumerable<AverageEmployeeHourModel>)averageEmployeeHourModelBindingSource.DataSource).Count() * 100 : 0;

            // Display the percentage in label_Percentage
            label_Percentage.Text = $"{percentage:F2}%";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```